# rails with MySQL AND a small redis store

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3.1, redis

I've got a Rails 3.1 app running a mysql server for storing data. 
90% of the data in the app fits really well in a relational database.

The other 10% is a pretty large hash that I need to pull out, change, and put back fairly quickly. It is a fairly large query in mysql to bring all these data pieces together, across multiple tables, but once I have it once, I figured I would save it as a hash, and the user can interact with the hash and make changes. Those changes never get persisted back to mysql, as mysql doesn't need them.

so, I decided to add redis to my rails application and the redis-objects gem was recommended by a friend.

I have created my `active_hash` model and controller as so

```
class ActiveHash < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Redis::Objects
end

class ActiveHashesController < ApplicationController

    def show
    #this is a big query with a bunch of merges, but simplified here as it isn't important
    active = Game.find(params[:id])

    active_hash_in_redis = ActiveHash.new()
        if active_hash_in_redis.save
            render :json => active_hash
        else
            render :text => "didn't save"
        end
    end

end
```

when I navigate to active_hashes/id, I get an error that there is no MySQL table active_hashes, which is right, because that is supposed to be my redis db, as defined in the model.

can anybody explain to me how to use both dbs in my app, and/or point me to a tutorial on doing this? I haven't been able to find anything. Is using Redis-Objects the wrong way to go with this?? Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was a bit of confusion on my part, but hopefully this helps somebody else.

I didn't end up using the redis-objects, gem, I installed redis-rb with `gem redis`. 
Then I set-up the config file as

```
require 'redis'
$redis = Redis.new()
```

My model is actually blank at the moment, in my controller, I've used

```
class ActiveHashesController < ApplicationController

    def show
    #this is a big query with a bunch of merges, but simplified here as it isn't important
    active = Game.find(params[:id])

    $redis.set params[:id], active.to_json
    get_game = $redis.get params[:id]
    render :json => get_game

        end
    end

end
```